# Open Cash Drawer +Linux +USB +Driver +Libusb

Tags: linux, usb, driver, pos

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, and have connected a USB Cash Drawer from Posiflex (Series 3.xxx).

**(No receipt printer - direct connection from USB on PC to Cash Drawer)**

The device is picked up in Linux as follows:

Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0d3a:0207 Posiflex Technologies, Inc. Series 3xxx Cash Drawer

/dev/hidraw1

Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/2p, 480M

```
|__ Port 5: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
```

The driver is listed as **usbhid** but I have no idea how to interface with it?

All I want to do is kick open the cash drawer, perhaps someone has a unique solution? Any help would be appreciated. There is no manufacturer driver for Linux.

Way down in the future I'd like to be able to kick open the drawer from within Wine, but that's a story for another day. Right now, I just want to kick the drawer open in Linux.

Thanks

Johan

Comment: Looking at the [Java POS Driver for Linux](http://www.posiflex.com/ja-JP/product/getFile?id=a22fedfe585e9cf60c1b841952d7648426c60b51e178379d3295a2abf1ce4561d8474c938d42be039cc1ebc236e74fbe6abcfde58fc669928386638efddc59fdZtuFvR0p7cfl%2FeUoQjmcCg1GvSOapTjEsBHpCzOBbdc%3D) document, it seems that you can access it with /dev/ttyACMx in Linux if you set it to RS232C (Vendor Class) mode by [Jumper setting - Download](http://www.posiflex.com/en-global/product/index/Cash-Drawer/Cash_Drawer/CR-3100_Series#download)?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, will look into it shortly.

Comment: Hi @kunif I installed JavaPOS as well as the PosTest app, and modified the jumper settings accordingly. After much monitoring, I found that /dev/ttyACMx was never listed upon connecting the cash drawer. I did test with other devices though and /dev/ttyACMx was registered where applicable. Any idea on the road forward now? It seems that /dev/ttyACMx is not a option to pursue?

Comment: The `readme_lux.txt` of JavaPOS Driver that I introduced has a description `"CR1" --> used for connecting to POSSystem. (drawer number 1)`, so I think there is some way. By the way, the port name described there is `/dev/ttySx`. On the other hand, it seems that only the cash drawer for printer connecting PPCR1 is described in the demo `jpos.xml`. If possible, contact the vendor based with such information.

Comment: Thank you for that, the vendor has no solution. We have purchased equipment for a more conventional approach, receipt printer with standard cash drawer. Pity though, I would have loved to know how to communicate on /dev/hidraw.... or /dev/usb/hiddev0, the default Linux-recognized 'ports' on system after re-connection. Your assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Only the vendor can answer what kind of command/response format is in HID mode. If that vendor doesn't answer, you'll need to take alternatives.